# Why does Redis (Nodejs) automatically updates its cache after new item has been added to database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, redis

I wanted to play around with Redis, so I wrote simple endpoint for fetching blogs and quite soon encountered the "sweet problem" since code does work, but I do not no why.

The idea was to store blogs in cache after the initial request, that behaved as expected, however, from my understanding, I should have experienced problems after I add new blog, but I did not. I will post the code for more visual explenation.

```
client.get = util.promisify(client.get);

    const cachedBlogs = await client.get(req.user.id);

    if (cachedBlogs) {
      return res.send(JSON.parse(cachedBlogs));
    }

    const blogs = await Blog.find({ _user: req.user.id });
    res.send(blogs);
    client.set(req.user.id, JSON.stringify(blogs));
```

From my understanding, the cache should be fine until I post new blog, since in that scenario `cachedBlogs` would equal to true as well, but I would only return previous version of cache since I never managed to store new blog to the cache. The problem is that I see new blog in the cache immediately after I add it and I do not why, since it always terminates in the `if statement` if cache is not empty.

So the more precise question is, how does redis store new data into cache considering this code ?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't cache at all? (not sure what the problem is though never worked with redis)

Comment: it does, since I can check whether I retrieved data from cache or from querying database

Comment: Hey I think you should be able to tell what's going on if you inspect the part of the code that deals with posting new blogs. Check if the method to post new blogs calls the client.set method.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think auto update is impossible.

So, you can add more log about redis and db; or you can debug your code. You will find your problem.